# When using MPI, how can I fix the error: "_int_malloc: Assertion `(unsigned long) (size) >= (unsigned long) (nb)' failed"?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, malloc, mpi

I'm using a scientific simulation code that my supervisor wrote about 10 years ago to run some calculations.  An intermittent issue keeps arising when running it in parallel on our cluster (which has hyperthreading enabled) using mpirun.  The error it produces is very terse, and simply tells me that a memory assignment has failed.

```
program-name: malloc.c:4036: _int_malloc: Assertion `(unsigned long) (size) >= (unsigned long) (nb)' failed.
[MKlabgroup:3448077] *** Process received signal ***
[MKlabgroup:3448077] Signal: Aborted (6)
[MKlabgroup:3448077] Signal code:  (-6)
```

I've used the advice [here](https://www.infor.uva.es/%7Eeduardo/blog/index.php/2016/05/09/debugging-mpi-programs-with-gdb/) to start the program and halt it so that I can attach a debugger session to one of the instances on a single core.  The error occurs during the partitioning of the input mesh (using metis) when a custom matrix function is called for the first time, and requests space for ~4000 rows and 4 columns, with each element being an 8 byte integer.  This particular function (below) uses an array of n pointers addressing m arrays of integer pointers:

```
int **matrix_int(int n, int m)
{
    int i;
    int **mat;
      
    // First: Assign the rows [n]
    mat = (int **) malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    if (!mat)
    {
        program_error("ERROR[0]: Memory allocation failure for the rows @[matrix_int()]");
    }
    
    // Second: Assign the columns [m]
    for (i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = (int *) malloc(m*sizeof(int));
        if (!mat[i])
        {
            program_error("ERROR[0]: Memory allocation failure for the columns @[matrix_int()]");
        }
    }

    return mat;
}
```

My supervisor thinks that the issue has to do with automatic resource allocation on the CPU. As such, I've recently tried using the -rf option in mpirun in conjunction with a rankfile specifying which cores to use, but this has produced similarly intermittent results; sometimes a single process crashes, sometimes several, and sometimes it runs fine. It always runs reliably in serial, but the calculations are extremely slow on a single core.

Does anyone know of a change to the server configuration or the code itself that I can make (aside from globally disabling hyperthreading) that would allow this to run for certain every time?

*(Any general tips on debugging in parallel would also be greatly appreciated! I'm still pretty new to C/C++ and MPI, and have another bug to chase after this one which is probably related.)*

Comment: 1. From your description it doesn't seem to have much to do with MPI. 2. Can you post the stack trace with all parameters? 3. Which of the two mallocs in that code snippet causes the error? 4. It's usually not a good idea to allocate a matrix this way. Better to allocate a single array of size `m*n`, and then translate any `i,j` index to a linear `i+j*m` or like that. But save that for a later rewrite: your code ought to work.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. If it crashes somewhere inside this code, then there is a fatal problem that occurred somewhere before this code had a chance to run. I recommend using either `-fsanitize=address,undefined` compiler switch or `valgrind`. Also read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Allocation-Debugging.html).

Comment: try `mat = (int **) malloc((long)n*sizeof(int*));` (same thing a bit later) to make sure `n*sizeof(int*)` is not truncated to an `int`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I've compiled and run with the compiler flags you suggested (also with -fsanitize=thread) and it seems like the assertion in malloc fails because of a segv fault during allocation. An array read overrun error was also reported earlier on in the program (I'm currently investigating this).  I'm currently thinking that this earlier issue may be causing subsequent allocations to fail.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout It's the first one that causes the error.  Since first posting the question I've seen the error occur when running in serial, so as you say it's probably not MPI.  Running in parallel simply increases the odds that the error will appear. (I still can't understand how it can be intermittent)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks for the tip.  I tried this but sadly it didn't solve the issue.  I did discover though that for my system `sizeof(int)=4` and `sizeof(int*)=8`.  Shouldn't `sizeof(int)=8` as well for a 64-bit OS? (I'm running recent desktop and server versions of Ubuntu)

Comment: `sizeof(int` is always `4`. you might confuse it with `sizeof(long)` that is `4` on 32 bits binaries and `8` on 64 bits binaries (since you might be able to run a 32 bits binary on a 64 bits OS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the compiler flags suggested by n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. to diagnose memory access violations I've discovered that the memory corruption is indeed caused by a function that is called just before the one in my original question.

The offending function reads in data from a text file using `sscanf`, and would allocate a 3-element array for each line of the file (for the 3 numbers to be read in per line).  The next part is conjecture, but I think that the problem arose because `sscanf` returns a `NULL` at the end of a sequence it reads.  I'm surmising that this `NULL` was written to the next byte along from the 3 allocated, such that the next time `malloc` tried to allocate data the first thing it saw was a `NULL`, causing it to return without actually having allocated any space.  Then the next function to try and use the allocated memory would come along and crash because it's trying to access unassigned memory that `malloc` had reported to be allocated.

I was able to fix the bug by changing the size of the allocated array in the read function from 3 to 4 elements.  This would seem to allow the `NULL` character to be stored without it interfering with subsequent memory allocations.